# How to make a bronze material in Cycles?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

how to achieve a bronze shader, optionally with some dirt?

Here is my Mesh:

[image]

And here is a reference image showing how it should look:

[image]

Comment: Glebe Alexandrov has a video on how to make a [grungy metal material](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6mbo474uhOA&list=UUVA3cYOgsTN4hs3v7pjne7w) (warning: he moves fast!).  You can procedurally tweak the colors of whatever texture you use with an rgb curves node to get the bronze color.

Comment: its nearly imposibble to follow that tutorial since it was made to animate people to buy the 3d magazine.

Comment: That's not really the purpose of the tutorial, that's just Gleb's style, all his videos are like that.  You have to do a lot of pausing and rewinding.  I am working on a bronze of my own based on Gleb's metal, I will post it if I get it done.

Comment: No dont get me wrong but its like here look textures overe here sliders over here and here i have some texture and groups and nodes and i dont know what and then I find in Description" Written tutorial with all steps covered in detail can be found in 3dWorld magazine. " seems to me like if you want it in detail buy this magazine i would be glad to see youre approach to the answer.

Comment: And did you got something ?

Comment: I haven't had time to work at it yet, maybe I'll get something over the weekend.

Comment: Ahh ok if just post it as answer ^^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what I came up with using procedural textures:

[image]

I would use *dirty vertex colors* in *3D view > header > Paint* while in *Vertex paint* mode to add some dirt to the corners:

[image]

You can then use this in your node setup via an *Attribute* node, with the *name* set to the name of the vertex color layer (`Col` by default):

[image]

---

You could more than likely get a better result more easily by using image textures.

I'd also recommend [this tutorial](http://www.creativeshrimp.com/2014/10/how-roughness-can-change-the-way-we-think-about-materials.html), which has some great examples (and a free image texture).

Comment: hmm i think i get into texturing i didnt see one statisfying result (and i tried my self already.)

Comment: Little offtopic: thumbs up for Suzanne with crista :)

Answer (score 6):

Here is my version of [Gleb Alexandrov's grungy metal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6mbo474uhOA&list=UUVA3cYOgsTN4hs3v7pjne7w).  I changed the color to a bronze using a couple of RGB curves and Bright/Contrast nodes and added some dirt using dirty vertex.  The rust is not technically accurate since bronze does not rust but I threw it in anyhow so you can see how it is done.  You can always bypass the rust by plugging the base metal shader right into the scratches mix shader node.  It looks great though without the bronze coloring on the base metal.

Here is the full material:

[image]

Here is just the base metal:

[image]

Full thing without rust:

[image]

Here is the node setup:

[image]

And finally the [blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/32556).

Both the base metal and the rust textures are free ones from [cgtextures.com](http://www.cgtextures.com), the scratch map is homemade.

If you don't want it to look that grungy you can mix the base metal with a bronze color using a mix RGB node and increase the left value of the color ramp coming out of the fresnel node to get more gloss.

Comment: The blend file is missing and the node images are too small? PGMath help!

Comment: @hawkenfox  I added an enlarged node tree image link.  I'll have to see if I can dig up the .blend.  I *think* I still have it sitting around somewhere.

Comment: thanks for your kind attention. The enlarge node tree didn't help much tho , the node group is too big and it's really hard to see on my screen.

Comment: The link is broken final blend file. plz share the file. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Okay After some Investigation and trying stuff i found this here http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?241389-Dirt-procedure
Here is the Node Setup for it too has Dirty Vertex Colors.

[image]

the result can be seen here. Of Course someone could Tweek the Colors / Mix Values for another Result look the thread up.

[image]

Comment: best looking and simplest shader here.

Comment: where is youre approach then i want to see that Bronze Material of yours ;) by the way bronze has a very wide meaining in terms of corlors if you noticed that was my own question and you acn alterate the colors in the node setup.

Answer (score 1):

If you download this [pack](http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/69793) and append in the *Brass Old* one, you can adjust its colors to get what you are looking for. Then hook a grunge map into the *Roughness* value, or use a noise texture like this:

[image]

This gives an output of:
[image]

By playing with the *Contrast* and *Multiply Values* you can get a pretty nice result.You can mix together more complex textures to get a look more like your image.