# Perfecting Procedural Texture for Long Vertical Cracks on Concrete Surface

Tags: texturing, materials, procedural

I hope you’re all doing well. I’ve been working on a project where I’m trying to create a procedural texture to depict long vertical cracks in a concrete surface, specifically, I am aiming for the look of flexural cracks, which occur at fixed distances apart.

So far, I have made some progress, but I am not entirely satisfied with the results I’m getting. It seems there’s a gap between what I have now and the vision I have in my mind.

Please find the attached images. The first one is the current state of the texture I am working on, and the second is the kind of texture I’m aiming to achieve. As you can see, I’m trying to improve the realism of the crack formation.

I’m using the concrete surface texture that I’ve already designed as a base for this, and I’d like to add the cracks on top of this. However, the cracks are not coming out as realistic as I want them to be. They either seem too artificial, too repetitive, or they don’t quite capture the nuances of flexural cracks on concrete surfaces.

Could anyone guide me on how I can improve my approach and get a more accurate and realistic texture? Any tips on techniques, tools, or methodologies to achieve this effect would be highly appreciated.

Also, I would be thankful if anyone could share some best practices to maintain the fixed distance between these cracks while keeping them look natural and realistic.

Cracks I generated:

[image]

[image]

Material nodes:

[image]

Cracks I want:

[image]

Comment: I have this answer which may give you some ideas - https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/207287/110840

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a *Brick* texture would be a good starting-point. It has some advantages:

- You can adjust the frequency of cross-cracks independently of the overall texture-scale, so their thickness is easier to control
- You can use the mortar 'Softness' setting to put a gradient onto a *Bump* node, or displacement
- The chunks of cement can have randomly-allocated colors, which might be used to tilt their normals

[image]

Above the texture-space is scaled, then sheared, then has Noise added to it for the wobble. The Noise is scaled independently in X and Y. A bit of color has been added to the bottom of the cracks for illustration. With full lighting, and your own base-color, you might just use the *Bump*

[image]

[image]

It's a first shot: see how you get on with tweaks. Happy to update.